# Where can I find which APIs gcloud calls?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm working on a new project where I plan to replace a collection of one-off shell scripts that call `gcloud` and `gsutil` with Google Cloud Go APIs and client libraries. The main driver behind this is so I can have easier to maintain and testable code to manage a large scale GCP automation project.

I've dug through all of the Google doc and cannot seem to find anything that covers what underlying APIs `glcoud` calls, or the `glcoud` source code. To add to this, the GCP go APIs don't seem to cover what I'm looking for. I have been able to find some of what I need offered in the REST APIs, but even then, it's not entirely clear what `gcloud` commands map to what REST API endpoints.

An example would be: `gcloud addresses describe gce_vm_foo`

The only thing I can find that fits is this endpoint from the REST API, found through digging through the enormous pile of documentation and trial and error: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#InstancesService.Get

I realize this is a very open ended question, but any pointing in the right right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to know what calls gcloud is making add --log-http flag and maybe grep for something to narrow down your search, for example:

```
~ gcloud --log-http compute addresses list 2>&1 | grep "GET" \
GET /compute/v1/projects/<redacted>/aggregated/addresses?alt=json HTTP/1.1
```

then possibly go to the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1) page and search (or just google) for the distinguishing part of the request uri from above, like 'aggregated/addresses', which should get you to the [REST Resource: v1.addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1#rest-resource:-v1.addresses) portion of the page and from here it should be relatively easy.